# Data Cleaning - removing trailing phrases

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm cleaning some data and wondering how to remove trailing phrases. I don't want to get rid of all numbers as some flavors have numbers. The first table is the pre-cleaned data, the second table is what I want.

| Flavor |
| --- |
| Orange 5 ml |
| Cherry |
| Strawberry 5 mg/ml |
| #1 flavor |
| Passion fruit 1. |
| Cherry Blossom |

| Flavor |
| --- |
| Orange |
| Cherry |
| Strawberry |
| #1 flavor |
| Passion fruit |
| Cherry Blossom |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all data cleansing, this requires knowledge of the entire dataset, so the help you can get is minimal. However, I've cooked up a regular expression that you can use to remove numbers, whitespace, units (`ml`, `mg`), slashes (`/`) and periods (`.`) from the *end* of the strings:

```regex
\s*\b[/mgl\d\s.]+$
```

You can use it like this:

```
df['Flavor'] = df['Flavor'].str.replace(r'\s*\b[/mgl\d\s.]+$', '', regex=True)
```